# ASP.NET MVC: OutputCache and http headers

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, http-headers

I have just started using OutputCache on some of my controller actions and I am not quite getting the response I would expect.

I have set the cache time to 5 minutes and the Expires header is coming up the same as the Last-Modified header which is the time that the request was made.

This is the header I am currently getting:

```
Date                    Thu, 16 Jul 2009 06:35:07 GMT
Server                  Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By            ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version        2.0.50727
X-AspNetMvc-Version     1.0
Content-Encoding        gzip
Cache-Control           public, max-age=300
Expires                 Thu, 16 Jul 2009 06:35:06 GMT
Last-Modified           Thu, 16 Jul 2009 06:35:03 GMT
Vary                    *
Content-Type            text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length          575
```

This is the header I would expect:

```
Date                    Thu, 16 Jul 2009 06:35:07 GMT
Server                  Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By            ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version        2.0.50727
X-AspNetMvc-Version     1.0
Content-Encoding        gzip
Cache-Control           public, max-age=300
Expires                 Thu, 16 Jul 2009 06:40:06 GMT
Last-Modified           Thu, 16 Jul 2009 06:35:03 GMT
Vary                    *
Content-Type            text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length          575
```

Any ideas on why it would be doing this?

Cheers
Anthony

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`max-age` takes precedence (from [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html)):

> We use the term `expires_value` to
>   denote the value of the Expires
>   header. We use the term
>   `max_age_value` to denote an
>   appropriate value of the number of
>   seconds carried by the "max-age"
>   directive of the Cache-Control header
>   in a response (see section 14.9.3).
>
> The max-age directive takes priority
>   over Expires, so if max-age is present
>   in a response, the calculation is
>   simply:
>
> ```
>   freshness_lifetime = max_age_value
> ```
>
> Otherwise, if Expires is
>   present in the response, the
>   calculation is:
>
> ```
>   freshness_lifetime = expires_value - date_value
> ```

So the client should use the cached version as you expect.

Comment: Humm does this only apply for HTTP/1.1? Because I am using a proxy that apparently only supports HTTP/1.0. So does this still apply?

Comment: What the proxy supports only makes a different to what the proxy does with the content. What headers are sent depends on the cache location specified in your output cache attribute.

Comment: The Cache-Control header was introduced in HTTP/1.1 to deal with limitations in the Expires header.  The issue is that the Expires header sets a fixed expiry date which can lead to issues if the client and server clocks are not synchronised.

When using a browser that supports HTTP/1.1 (pretty much all browsers), the Expires header is ignored in favour of the Cache-Control - max-age header.  The only time the Expires header is used is when the request comes from a browser that only supports HTTP/1.0, not HTTP/1.1.